# Calling plugin onContentPrepare, from category blog view (joomla)

Tags: joomla, field, categories

I found this page on how to implement custom field in article:

```
http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component
```

and it works well, but only in `article` view.

What should I do else, to make it show that custom field in each article, when
in `category blog` view?

I tried adding :

```
$dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('content', 'plg_content_rating');
$results = $dispatcher->trigger('onContentPrepare',
    array('com_content.category', & $this->item, & $this->item->params, 0));
```

to my `category blog` override file, but that didn't work.

Also in `components/com_content/views/category/view.html.php` file,
there is a line like this:

```
$results = $dispatcher->trigger('onContentPrepare',
    array ('com_content.category', &$item, &$this->params, 0));
```

Shouldn't that already trigger all registered content plugins?

The similar line in `article's` view.html.php file, works well for that
purpose.

Comment: Please try asking your question at the dedicated [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) site :)

Comment: @Lodder I didn't know it exists.